# Mouse gestures for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, mouse-gestures

Is there an application that can give me mouse gestures across all programs on Windows 7? I'm aware of [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/), but it seems to have some nasty bugs on 64-bit versions of Windows. (Or maybe it's just mine, I don't know, but it crashed a lot last time I used it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When did you last try Strokeit? There is [a new version](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) available, works like a charm on my Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Interesting. I must have tried it right before that version came out, because it was around that time. I'll download it and try again, and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. It looks like you're right, it works! Thanks! :)

Comment: What about Windows 10? Does it work smoothly? I can tell that life without Strokeit is going to be depressing.

Answer (score 11):

[StrokesPlus](http://www.strokesplus.com) is very similar to StrokeIt, but more powerful.  It comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.  One thing with StrokeIt is you can't launch 64-bit native Windows apps like Task Manager or Calculator, it instead opens the 32-bit version.

StrokesPlus also has mouse/key modifiers and many other advanced features, though the actions are in Lua script instead of GUI elements...so there's a trade-off between ease of setup and power/flexibility.

I built StrokesPlus from the ground up in native C++ (no hefty MFC or .NET runtimes required) primarily due to StrokeIt's developer not keeping his app up-to-date or addressing user requests.  So yes, I'm quite biased, but StrokesPlus is freeware, so I'm not really getting anything special out of this =)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing this! I will definitely give it a try and let you know what I think. :)

Comment: Sending key combinations isn't working with locales other than english (at least with "english+other") which may be a showstopper for somebody http://www.strokesplus.com/forum/topic/357/workaround-acsendkeys-on-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

There is also new mouse gestures application called [Just Gestures](http://justgestures.com) which is also available for 64-Bit windows. It's very intuitive but still allows more advanced users to create complex actions and custom gestures. Moreover it introduces Rocker gestures (but called Double Button gesture) and gestures performed by pressing mouse button and moving with wheel.

Comment: Tried it out, and it's really cool! It's a lot like StrokeIt, only has the advantage of allowing you to draw custom gestures, and the "per-application" feature is better. The interface is somewhat inefficient, as it takes more steps to complete most things than in StrokeIt, but I can live with that. Thanks again for the post! I would accept this as the answer if I hadn't already accepted @CGA's answer.

Comment: Crashes on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of all of the native Windows 7 mouse gestures? Shaking a window by its toolbar will minimize other windows for example.

Comment: Windows provides about three actions that are not customizable. Those aren't really what I'd call mouse gestures...

Comment: You're right, they're more shortcuts than gestures.